# Where should plot tiles go after choosing one to place?

Tags: takenoko

When draw 3 tiles to place one, should the 2 remaining ones go on the top or on the bottom of the draw pile? The rules only say that the player draw 3 and chooses one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the rules [here](https://www.matagot.com/docs/Takenoko_rules_EN.pdf) on page 5.

> The player draws three plots, chooses one and places the other two
> back on top of the deck, face- down in the order of his choice.

The rules you quote above were on page 4 but it is explained in more detail on next page.

Comment: The rules that came with my game indicate the other 2 tiles go under the deck, not on top. Could this have been an update to the rules?